# Tomcat provide static content folder as welcome page

Tags: tomcat, static

This is my folder structure:

```
META-INF
static
WEB-INF
```

And /static is available with all its contents and dependencies. How can I make that folder to be the start page.

This line in the web.xml file breaks all the .js and .css files

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/static/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Like in express I could just write

```
.use('/', express.static('/static'))
```